# Featured Content block inside node

Tags: 7

I'm using Drupal 7 and trying to include the Featured Content block between the write up and the comments, i.e. I want it inside a node.

I tried the method explained [here](http://drupal.org/node/1034524#comment-4100718), but am not getting the block appear.

This is the code I've used in my node.tpl.php

`$block = module_invoke('featured_content', 'block_view', '1');
print render($block);`

The featured content block's URL contains this:

admin/structure/block/manage/featured_content/1/configure

Any suggestions? What could I be missing out?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in another [post](http://drupal.org/node/1034524#comment-4745178), I used this code:

```
$block = block_load('featured_content', '1');
$output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
print $output;
```

This worked perfectly!